# Schema validation error / Thread safety of XmlSchemaSet?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Good afternoon,

An XML schema validation snippet is working fine on development/q&a environments, but is yielding some odd validation results in Production. The usual suspect would be that the code is unsafe for threading, and that the additional load of the Production scenario is flushing out the error.

The exact scenario is as follows. Consider that the XML being validated is:

```
<mssql:spExecute type="ResultSet" xmlns:mssql="urn:namespace">
    <mssql:actor>IPASS</mssql:actor>
    <mssql:connection>ConnectionString</mssql:connection>
    <mssql:storedProcedure>dbo.RedFox</mssql:storedProcedure>
</mssql:spExecute>
```

In the course of a full day, around 300 executions (of >2M) will yield the following exception:

```
System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException
The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/:mssql' attribute is not declared.
```

The schema validator seems to complain about the namespace declaration.

The code structure is as follows:

- There is a static instance of XmlSchemaSet;
- Initialization of the XmlSchemaSet instance is being done in a thread-safe manner;
- Each worker thread makes use of the same XmlSchemaSet;
- The validation occurs during an XmlSerializer.Deserialize() call, using an XmlReader with XmlReaderSettings initialized with ValidationType.Schema.

Any thoughts on what might be causing the validation to choke with the namespace declaration?

Answer (score 5):

1. Is what you describe a result of a controlled experiment or
   an observation from production environment?
   If the latter, try reproducing it in a controlled setup to make sure some other
   bug is not a real cause.
2. [The documentation for `XmlSchemaSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx) says:

   > "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

   This includes property reads and "read-only" methods.
   So we cannot assume that read-only use of `XmlSchemaSet` would be thread safe.
   Until Microsoft provides implementation that explicitly allows sharing of the same compiled
   schema representation between threads, the only safe thing to do is not to share.
3. OTOH it seems logical to share single compiled immutable `XmlSchemaSet` to validate
   multiple `XmlDocument` (or `XmlReader`) instances.
   It is a very sensible scenario, so I don't understand why it is not explicitly
   permitted and documented.

   (Update: Apparently this is explicitly guaranteed in [Java's standard XML library](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html).
   Why isn't it so in .NET?)

Comment: The documentation doesn´t mention it anymore, should we understand is it thread safe now?

Answer (score 2):

This may be fixed in .NET 4.0, but not documented.

I encountered the same error in a production web service. The error is similar, and random during peak activity: "*The xxx element is not declared*". However in my case we are just validating the XML with a looped Read command, rather than serializing an object.

The service is built/running under .NET 3.5, and in a development environment I can easily replicate this error by launching 5 threads and simultaneously making a service call. The error occurs about 1 in 10 requests.

When I sat down to address this issue, the first thing I did was upgrade the service to .NET 4.0. As soon as I did this, I cannot produce this error any more. I increased the thread count and removed service throttling - still no errors.

While the current documentation still indicates that XmlSchema instance operations are not guaranteed thread safe, there appears to have been some framework change between 3.5 and 4.0 that improves the thread safety for read/validation type operations on XmlSchema.

Comment: Also note that if that had not worked, I likely would have created a list of the XmlSchema objects on start up and wrapped access to them such that only one is used per thread. I believe the creation of the objects carries some cost and is better not to create one on each request.

Comment: Good information! I also did a similar test and the result seems to indicate no break on running 100 concurrent threads with each reading and validating an XML doc, sharing the same XmlSchemaSet. However even with that, I wouldn't trust it until MSDN explicit says it is thread safe to use. It seems to be a good idea of having a pool of pre-compiled schema objects and grab one for each thread to use and to return to the pool when finished.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems that XML validation is not a read-only operation, which this article indicates:

http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2009/04/27/xmlschemaset-thread-safety.aspx

Sticking a lock around it solved the problem for me.

Comment: No. It's not. Read again. The article says that validation uses only read-only operations on `XmlSchemaSet` so multiple threads can share single `XmlSchemaSet` instance without explicit locks.

It points out that a) `XmlSchemaSet` construction is not thread safe and b) you need to make sure the `ValidationEventHandler` callback you provide is thread-safe.
Both are pretty obvious.

What it does not say is _why it assumes read-only operations on `XmlSchemaSet` are indeed thread-safe_. Documentation says "any instance members [including property reads --ts] are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Comment: Could you elaborate? By what definition of read-only? Is there any official definition what "read-only operation" means in .NET Framework? __And how to say---looking at a class from outside---if an operation is read-only?__ Remember, any kind of lazy evaluation results in an operation that---while externally read-only---changes internal state of an object.

For `XmlSchemaSet`, which is compiled before use, it makes sense to expect that all reads are truly read-only. The problem is, documentation doesn't say so openly and I'm not sure if I can safely cache compiled schema.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, intermittent `The 'uri:elem' element is not declared.` running multi-threaded validations using shared `XmlSchemaSet` on `Environment.Version=="4.0.30319.42000"`.

These problems went away when compiling the set;

```
var schema = XmlSchema.Read(xmlReader, null);
var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add(schema);
schemaSet.Compile(); // <<<< added this
// multi-threaded validation using per-thread XmlReaderSettings
// with settings.Schemas.Add(schemaSet)
```