# Multithreaded xml validation against schema with biztalk schema collection in C#

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, biztalk, xsd-validation

I was trying to validate the schema using below code

```
 string[] assemblyNameParts = schemaStrongName.Split(new char[] { ',' }, PARTS_IN_SCHEMA_STRONG_NAME);
            string className = assemblyNameParts[PART_CLASS_NAME].Trim();
            string fullyQualifiedAssemblyName = assemblyNameParts[PART_QUALIFIED_ASSEMBLY_NAME].Trim();

            Assembly schemaAssembly = Assembly.Load(fullyQualifiedAssemblyName);
            Type schemaType = schemaAssembly.GetType(className);
            SchemaBase btsSchemaCollection = (SchemaBase)Activator.CreateInstance(schemaType);

            XmlReaderSettings xmlReadeSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            //xmlReadeSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
            xmlReadeSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            xmlReadeSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints;// | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes;
            foreach (XmlSchema xschema in btsSchemaCollection.SchemaCollection)
            {
                String schemaXMl = xschema.ToString();
               xmlReadeSettings.Schemas.Add(xschema);
               //XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(new StringReader(schemaXMl));//, (sender, args) => { });
            }

            xmlReadeSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);

            XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(requestMessage.OuterXml));
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlTextReader, xmlReadeSettings);

            while (xmlReader.Read()) ;
            xmlReader.Close();
```

But I came to know that XMLSchema is not threadsafe as mentioned in below link

[Multithreaded xml validation against schema in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389976/multithreaded-xml-validation-against-schema-in-net)

Now my question is how to Cache the schema as string for btsSchemaCollection.SchemaCollection

I need to use below code

```
 XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(new StringReader(schemaXml), (sender, args) => { });
            settings.Schemas.Add(schema);
```

and replace below code

```
foreach (XmlSchema xschema in btsSchemaCollection.SchemaCollection)
            {
                String schemaXMl = xschema.ToString();
               xmlReadeSettings.Schemas.Add(xschema);
               //XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(new StringReader(schemaXMl));//, (sender, args) => { });
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain as bit first on exactly why you're trying to do this?  I know the problem, but it's mostly irrelevant since there are more correct ways to validate in BizTalk apps.

Comment: When I drop multiple file at the same time.. My validation is failing for some files.....When I drop 1 file at a time it works.

Comment: I am trying to validate the input messages.

Comment: Well, the question is why are you trying to do this in code rather than the regular BizTalk ways?

Comment: the schema has more than 200 root nodes..when we try to add those nodes in document spec property of the pipeline ..it fails with outofmemory error.

Comment: Well, does it really have 200 Root Nodes?  Or are those just Element definitions?

Comment: just Element definitions

Comment: Have you set the Root Reference on the <Schema> node?  Or, then why are you trying to add all 200 to the Doc Spec list? If they're only Element definitions, you don't need to do that.

Comment: Let me try that as well.